# Scrapy Json Rule SgmlLink Extractor

Tags: python, json, scrapy, web-crawler, sgml

I just want to know on how can I make rule when the website sends me a json response instead of html? On the start url first response, it gives me an html response, but when I navigated through pages, it gives me json response. Here my rule:

```
 Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//div[@class="GridTimeline-items"]'), tags=('div'),
                                   attrs=('data-min-position'), allow=(r''), process_value=my_process_value_friends),
                                    callback='parse_friends', follow=True),
```

My question is, how can I apply xpath on json response?

Thank you ,

Comment: You should use `scrapy.linkextractors.Linkextractor` since `SgmlLinkExtractor` has been deprecated for a while now. Those two are essentially the same thing though.

Answer (score 0):

You can't parse json with xpath or css selectors. You can however turn the json to python dictionary:

```
import json
def parse(self, response):
    data = json.loads(response.body)
    # then just parse it, e.g.
    item = dict()
    item['name'] = data['name']
    # ...
```

Or you can conver json to xml and then parse it with scrapy selectors. There a lot of packages that do that but I'll highlight [`dicttoxml`](https://github.com/quandyfactory/dicttoxml) in my example:

```
import json
from dicttoxml import dicttoxml
from scrapy import Selector
def parse(self, response):
    data = json.loads(response.body)
    data_xml = dicttoxml(data)
    sel = Selector(root=data_xml)
    # then parse it
    item = dict()
    item['name'] = sel.xpath("//name/text()")
    # ...
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am looking for solution for rules, not on the parsing stage

Comment: @Reymark You can't use `restrict_xpath` on json source without extending how CrawlSpider works. Easy way of doing it though, would be to do it manually as I described in my answer. Just have `parse` callback in your LinkExtractor and check whether the page is json at the beginning, if so find json urls, otherwise continue as normally.